# Determinar rota de acordo com a url que chamou o request

Tags: route, laravel-5.6

Minha situação é a seguinte, estou utilizando uma forma de cobrança que faz todo o sistema de assinatura online, o sistema ao realizar o cadastro de um cliente e validar o pagamento do mesmo, libera o acesso por 30 dias...

Porém ao término deste tempo terei de fazer uma forma de "bloqueio" do sistema, já fiz tudo o que preciso, porém cheguei a um código que satisfaz o que preciso.

Criei um middleware que me auxilia a receber e validar os clientes que tem o plano expirado, o resultado para qualquer rota que eu acessar é este (que é o resultado esperado):
[image: Assinaturas]

Porém ao dar o refresh na página ele não entra mais no middleware `Validade`...

> Validade.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Empresa as Empresa;
use Closure;
use Auth;

class Validade{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        $empresa = Empresa::where('id', Auth::user()->idglobal)->first();

        $databx = new \DateTime();
        $datavc = new \DateTime($empresa->permissao_uso); 

        $diasatraso = ($databx->diff($datavc)->format('%r%a') < 0) ? $databx->diff($datavc)->format('%a') : 0;

        if($diasatraso > 0){
            return redirect('lanc')->withErrors(['Plano Expirado' => '[Plano Expirado!] - Adquira um novo pacote de serviços para continuar usufruindo de nossos serviços!']);
        }else{
            return $next($request);
        }   
    }
}
```

> kernel

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [

            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'validade' => \App\Http\Middleware\Validade::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];
}
```

Nas minhas rotas tenho um `Route::group` que contém todas as rotas que são validadas por este middleware junto com o middleware `web`, está funcionando perfeitamente:

> web.php

```php
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
//rotas de autenticação
Auth::routes();

//Aqui está meu problema
route::resource('lanc', 'LancamentoController')->middleware('auth');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'middleware' => 'validade'], function()
{
    //produtos
    Route::resource('produtos','ProdutoController');

    //restante das rotas ocultas...
}
```

No caso todas as minhas rotas são validadas... minha dúvida é se existe alguma forma de eu fazer com que eu diga para as rotas de onde está vindo a requisição,  selecionar o middleware e fazer o handler da requisição em questão..

Não sei se consegui ser claro o suficiente, desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi de uma forma bastante simples:

Tirei a responsabilidade do redirecionamento das rotas e joguei isso no meu controller, em resumo o meu middleware ficou assim:

> Validade.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Empresa as Empresa;
use Closure;
use Auth;

class Validade{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        $empresa = Empresa::where('id', Auth::user()->idglobal)->first();

        $databx = new \DateTime();
        $datavc = new \DateTime($empresa->permissao_uso); 

        $diasatraso = ($databx->diff($datavc)->format('%r%a') < 0) ? $databx->diff($datavc)->format('%a') : 0;

        if($diasatraso > 0){
            return redirect('lanc');
        }else{
            return $next($request);
        }   
    }
}
```

Removi o envio do erro por aqui e joguei dentro da função index no meu controller:

> LancamentoController.php

```
<?php

//cabeçalho oculto...

class LancamentoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $lanc = Lancamento::where('idglobal', Auth::user()->idglobal)->get();

        $empresa = Empresa::where('id', Auth::user()->idglobal)->first();

        $databx = new \DateTime();
        $datavc = new \DateTime($empresa->permissao_uso); 

        $diasatraso = ($databx->diff($datavc)->format('%r%a') < 0) ? $databx->diff($datavc)->format('%a') : 0;

        if($diasatraso > 0){
            return view('Financeiro.resumo', ['lancamentos'=> $lanc])->withErrors(['Plano Expirado' => '[Plano Expirado!] - Adquira um novo pacote de serviços para continuar usufruindo de nossos serviços!']);
        }else{
            return view('Financeiro.resumo', ['lancamentos'=> $lanc]);
        }

    }

//Código oculto
}
```